# Load JavaAgent on JVM

Tags: java, javaagents

I have a theoretic question about java Agents. It's posible do a java or openJDK instruction to add a java agent before execute java?

The normally execution of javaagent (i discard runtime execution) is:

```
java -jar -javaagent myJavaAgent myProgram.jar
```

But my idea is create a docker container with OpenJDK version and my agent load

**PersonalJDK**

```
FROM openjdk:7
RUN java LOAD AGENT // I DONT KNOW THIS INSTRUCTION
```

**the customer use my container with my agent load**

```
FROM personalJDK:7
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", "Main"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching solutions i come with this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html

The answer is using _JAVA_OPTIONS, you must include a enviroment variables includes java agent.

**PersonalJDK**

```
FROM openjdk:7
COPY . /agent
RUN _JAVA_OPTIONS=-javaagent:/agent/myagent.jar
```

**the customer use my container with my agent load**

```
FROM PersonalJDK
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", -jar, "Main.jar"]
```

Comment: That’s nonsense. You can specify the command line option without an environmental variable, to the same result, `java -javaagent:/path/myagent.jar -jar myprogram.jar`. You can use that instead of the distorted command line posted in your question. It’s not clear which actual problem this Q&A is supposed to solve.

Comment: But don't worry i reedited my anwser, for people that can't follow my flow

Comment: You should have edited the question instead, so that “people that can't follow your flow” have a chance to understand what actual problem you are trying to solve.